# SQL select values with null result

Tags: sql, mysql

How to select values in sql with null result
For example we have next table

| user | code |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | code 1 |
| user3 | code 2 |
| user4 | code 4 |

Select
`select * from table where user in ( 'user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4')`

Result from select will be next

| user | code |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | code 1 |
| user2 |  |
| user3 | code 2 |
| user4 | code 4 |

How to select values in sql with null result

Comment: What MySQL version used?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by passing your condition as a subquery then apply `left join` with your table :

```
select s.user, t.code
from (
  select 'user1' as user union all 
  select 'user2' union all 
  select 'user3' union all 
  select 'user4' 
) as s
left join mytable t on s.user = t.user;
```

Results :

| user | code |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | code 1 |
| user2 | null |
| user3 | code 2 |
| user4 | code 4 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/egXG5vFm)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly filter it in where clause

```
select user,code
from (
  select 'user1' as user, 'abc' as code union all 
  select 'user2','def' union all 
  select 'user3', 'ghi' union all 
  select 'user4' ,NULL
) as s
where code is null;
```